# Testing a private method without call in Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, mocking

In my Java app, I want to test the following public method:

```
@Override
public List<ProductDTO> findByZoneOffset(final int zoneOffset) {
    final List<String> zoneIdList = getTimeZonesByZoneOffset(zoneOffset);
   
    final List<UUID> productConfigUuidList = 
        productConfigRepository.findAllUuidByZoneIdIn(zoneIdList);
    final List<Product> products = 
        productRepository.findAllBySiteConfigUuidIn(productConfigUuidList);

    return getProductDTOList(product);
}
```

There is a private method that is called the previous public method:

```
private static List<String> getTimeZonesByZoneOffset(final int zoneOffset) {
    return ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()
            .stream()
            .filter(zoneId -> ZoneId.of(zoneId)
                    .getRules()
                    .getOffset(Instant.now())
                    .equals(ZoneOffset.ofHours(zoneOffset)))
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I create the following unit test for testing `findByZoneOffset()` method. **However, I cannot evaluate the same values for** `zoneIdList` **as I can in the service method** (`getTimeZonesByZoneOffset`) **and for this reason** `productConfigUuidList` **value in the service returns empty list**.

```
@Test
public void test_findByZoneOffset() {
    final int numRecords = 3;
    final List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

    final List<String> zoneIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    zoneIdList.add("Africa/Nairobi");
    zoneIdList.add("Asia/Baghdad");
    zoneIdList.add("Europe/Moscow");

    final List<UUID> productConfigUuidList = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<ProductConfig> productConfigList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
        final Product product = new Product();
        final ProductConfig productConfig = new ProductConfig();
        productConfig.setZoneId(zoneIdList.get(i));
        productConfigUuidList.add(productConfig.getUuid());
        productConfigList.add(productConfig);
        product.setProductConfigUuid(productConfig.getUuid());
        productList.add(product);
    }

    when(productConfigRepository.findAllUuidByZoneIdIn(zoneIdList))
        .thenReturn(productConfigUuidList);
    when(productRepository.findAllBySiteConfigUuidIn(productConfigUuidList))
        .thenReturn(productList);
    when(productRepository.findAll(any(ProductCriteriaRequest.class)))
        .thenReturn(productList);
    when(productConfigRepository.findAllByUuidIn(anyList()))
        .thenReturn(productConfigList);

    final List<ProductDTO> productDTOList = 
        productService.findByZoneOffset(numRecords);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++) {
        assertEquals(zoneIdList.get(i), 
            productDTOList.get(i).getConfig().getZoneId());
    }
}
```

So, how should I mock `zoneIdList` in the test method with the same values as in service method without calling private method?

Please note that the private method is `static` and I am not sure if I can test it even I move it to my `Util` class and make it `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another method that is protected (private to the package or subclasses). This new method does nothing but call the private method.

Then you add a unit test class that resides in the same package and can test that private method.

In code this would look as trivial as

```
private static List<String> getTimeZonesByZoneOffset(final int zoneOffset) {
    return ...
}

protected static List<String> getTimeZonesByZoneOffset2(final int zoneOffset) {
    return getTimeZonesByZoneOffset(zoneOffset);
}
```

Then write a unit test for getTimeZonesByZoneOffset2.

Comment: Why do not you post this as answer? I mean, why do not add code to your answer? That will be much more useful for everyone.